# Change data type using Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Allow me to ask again this question, as answers found on the forum did not help me so far.

I am trying to convert a column from 'string' into 'numerical' data type.

The column has no missing values and no errors, it comes from a CSV file. For the record, I tried modifing the format type of the column on the CSV file and saving it as a number, but later when importing the CSV file on Azure ML it was coded as string.

So far, I have tried the following options:

- '**Execute Python scrip**t'. Unfortunately it does not work . It returns an error when I run the experiment. The Code I entered is:

  ```
  import pandas as df

  def azureml_main (df):
    df.age=pd.to_numeric(df.age,errors=’coerce’)

  return df
  ```
- Use '**Edit Metadata**' module. Select as Datatype: 'Integer' or 'Floating point' but I keep on getting an error when running the experiment.

Please kindly let me know what your thoughts are.

Thanks for your help.

Josep Maria

P.S: It's the second time I write in this forum. I hope this time it is well formulated.
[screenshot of 'Execute Python Script' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glLFo.jpg)

Comment: What errors are you getting for each of those options that you tried? And can you give a sample of the data or let us know where you got it?

Comment: hi @Jon thanks for answering. How can I provide a screenshot of the error? It's errorcode 0085. Will it be ok if I update original question with a screenshot?

Comment: Yeah, you can update with a screenshot. :)

Comment: Thanks @Jon, screenshot uploaded on original question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A couple of things to try in your script. Manually type in the quotes. It looks like it copied the formatting and that may cause errors. Also, try changing the indenting of the method. Python uses whitespace so if that's off that can also cause errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jon. I tried as per your suggestions, but unfortunately the problem remains. I even tried changing the Python (anconda 2.7, 3.5), etc. What else could I try?

Comment: Oh! I think I see the issue. Use `import pandas as pd` instead in the first line of the script. And in the `azureml_main` function signature, make sure it is this - `def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):`. The, since `dataframe1` is already a pandas dataframe, you just need to write the method as `dataframe1.age = pd.to_numeric(df.age, errors="coerce")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Python script just needs a little updating. :)

This should work since you get `dataframe1` automatically as a `pandas` data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
  dataframe1.age = pd.to_numeric(dataframe1.age, errors="coerce")

  return dataframe1
```